# generating skewed normal distribution in R

Tags: r, sampling

I would like to draw a sample from a normal distribution such that its mean is eg. 1.

How could I do this in R?
(I saw many examples with discrete distributions but not for continuous.)

Comment: you mean rnorm(1000, mean=1, sd=1)?

Comment: no, this would be a normal distribution with a mean of 1, I would like to simulate a biased sample from a normal distribution (skewed to the right)

Comment: in that case it is rsn(n=1000, xi=0, omega=1, alpha=0, tau=0, dp=NULL) from the sn package

Comment: edited the title, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get 1000 samples

```
samples <- rnorm(1000, mean=1, sd=1)
```

After some clarification, we now know that the sample should be skewed normal

```
library(sn)
rsn(n=1000, xi=0, omega=1, alpha=0, tau=0, dp=NULL)
```

Comment: What if you want to generate a skewed distribution with a particular mean? In your first example above using `rnorm()`, you can specify whatever mean and standard deviation you want. Can you do something like that with `rsn()`?